# What can cause a connection reset when site is visited with Firefox?

Tags: godaddy, firefox, error

I have a site on Godaddy and in the last few days whenever I visit a page on the site with Firefox I get a connection reset error first and I have to reload the page manually to load it.

I haven't changed anything on the site recently and the problem occurs only with Firefox, not with Opera/IE/Chrome. Apparently, my visitors also experience this, because I have a huge drop in visits on the site.

Is it a Godaddy problem? Something they did? But then why no other browser is affected, only Firefox?

Or can it be an issue with the newest version of Firefox, so it's not Godaddy's fault?

Anyone else experience such errors with Godaddy and/or Firefox?

Comment: as of 11/15 the problem between GoDaddy and WP did not go away! Godaddy blames WP and WP blames GoDaddy. When ever I edit in WP admin edit, (edit time, approx 1 min) by the time i select preview before upload, a new window opens and says The Connection Was Reset While The Page Was Loading. All indications based on what research I have done, points to Godaddy. Godaddy will not admit to anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was Godaddy's fault. They [applied some filters](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/the-connection-was-reset-error-message/?topic_page=5) on their servers which caused the connection reset error.

Comment: What was GoDaddy doing? What was in that link? It is broken.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, it was quite long ago and godaddy forums have been shut down since then, so the link stopped working. It was some kind of security measure against DOS attacks if I remember right, but it was too broad and it resetted legitimate connections too, so they removed the filter and the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

When you see  "The connection was reset," it means that the computer in-between yours and the server sent a TCP Reset packet before the data transfer was complete.

Sometimes this is a problem with the internet connection or ISP (I find the happens frequently with Virgin in the UK), it's more often caused by a configuration issue or corruption of the data stored locally on your computer.

1. Clear your browser's cache and all locally stored data including cookies.
2. Use www.iptools.com to ping and tracert to your website, look for hops or response times that are greater than normal.
3. If the response time problem is with your server, contact your hosting provider.

It's **very unlikly** that this is causing a drop in traffic to your website, this sort of thing is almost always a local problem.

Comment: Why is a drop in traffic unlikely to has a connection with this? If the average user clicks over from the search results and immediately encounters an error page from the browser (connection reset) then he very likely closes the window and tries another search result, so there is no visit. It does not usually occur to non technical users to reload the page if they see an error. BTW, apparently [others also see this problem](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/the-connection-was-reset-error-message/?topic_page=1&num=15).

Comment: @Tom I'm saying 99 times out of 100 this problem is down to your internet service provider and based on the evidence provided it sounds like this is your problem. Have you checked your website's headers to see if there is a problem?